# Manager misled me about the group I am in now. What should I do?

Tags: interviewing, resignation

I was interviewed with a recruiting manger of a company a few months back and finally I joined the company as I like the job responsibilities. However, after joining the company, on the first day it self, I have identified that the group (say B) is not the one that I thought of joining. My current manager was leading another group (say A) previously and that is the group (A) I am interested in. Since I know this person for a while as the manager of the group A, I focused only on my job responsibilities during my interview. Neither I have asked questions about his current group B nor he told me about the group B during the interview process. This is the only one mistake I have made. During my interview I thought that he is still the manager of the group A.

Moreover, on the first day of my job, my current manager added some different responsibilities to my job which he never discussed with me during my interview. However, I have politely rejected those responsibilities and somehow he seems to be okay with that.

However, as he promised me earlier (regarding projects), he allowed me to work on those projects. Although I am fine with my current projects, the kind of project that I am doing now is different from the projects of other team members of my current group (B). My project is similar to the projects of Group A. I needed to take help from the members of Group A for my project. Therefore, I feel alone in my current group. I am very upset because I think that my current manager intentionally misleaded me.

Therefore, last month I told my current manager that I wanted to move to Group A as the manager of Group A is very much interested to me to take in. He told me to continue a few more months in the group B.

Moreover, I have identified that there is some friction (politics) between the managers of group A and B. Please let me know how to handle this issue without damaging the relationships between me and my manager (the company).

Comment: It sounds like you handled it, and you are simply waiting on a response.  If I am mistaken, please clarify your question.

Comment: @jcmeloni: Thank you for your time. I would like to handle this issue without damaging the relationships between me and my current manager (the company).

Comment: Unfortunately, this really seems like it focuses too much on the specifics of your situation, and won't be too useful for future users who see it. If you could generalize it, I would happily upvote, but in the meantime I am voting to close.

Comment: @jmac: It is fine. It is specific because it is "really" happened to me. How can anyone generalize it?

Comment: And because it is so specific to you and your very specific situation that is linked with those specific details, it isn't likely to help people in the future (what are the chances that someone will have this exact same problem, and find this question as the solution?). Even if the situation is specific, the advice requested should be more broad and general so it has a chance to help people in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that you feel that you've been mislead by the interview procedure of your company. It also seems clear that you wish to join one group, but you feel that you have been doomed to work with another. It also seems clear that the manager of your current group isn't happy to see you go. Therefore, it seems that the easiest approach would be to follow these steps, terminating at any step that succeeds in getting you what you want:

- Speak to the person who interviewed you and make it clear that you don't feel that your current responsibilities match up with those that were offered during the initial interview. See if they're willing to rectify this on their own behalf. I've dealt with hiring proceedings myself in the past, and I've always felt bad when I've ended up assigning someone to a role that differs from what I laid out to them during their interview; the person who interviewed you might intervene on your behalf.
- Speak to your manager, the manager of group B. Point out that what you're doing for group B is different to what you were tacitly promised during your interview, and that you'd prefer to be doing what your interviewer promised. You never know, the manager of group B might be able to put you on something closer to what you wanted.
- Speak to the manager of group A. Point out what you've done so far, the skills you could bring to group A, and that you're willing to join. Openly ask them if they want you. It's always (always!) better to get someone more senior than you to represent your cause to managers/another department than it is to represent it yourself.
- Leave the company and go elsewhere to get what you want. If no group is willing to give you the work you want, then start looking for other job offers that will. No-one should damn themselves into going down a career path that will end up pigeon-holing them into work they don't want just to appear 'grateful for work' (despite what other answers have implied).

Whilst you may ultimately have to look elsewhere for the work you want, attempt to get it solved by appealing to the relevant parties inside work first.

I strongly support attempting to get what you want out of work. Try any route you can think of to make your job match up to what you want it to be; you're going to spend a significant proportion of your life at work, so you may as well get what you want out of it. In my opinion (and it's worked well for me in my career), you shouldn't ever accept the opinions of those who say that you should just be grateful for whatever meager circumstance you find yourself in: Always campaign for what you want.

Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome. Never settle for second best with your career, because just 'feeling lucky to have a job' will lead you into endless terrible jobs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered getting a second opinion from either the manager of group A or someone else in the company outside of group B?  If you are a good worker, there are some reasons for the manager to try to hold you into group B for as long as he can.  While this could be seen as childish, the key here is that if you make him look good, then he may not want to lose you to another group.  Thus, I'd probably consider following up with the manager of group A or go to HR directly to see that steps are being taken and how is this looking as you may well be making another mistake here by accepting what he says without checking it out.

While you state not asking about which group he runs was the only mistake you did, I'd be tempted to think you are putting a great deal of trust into someone that may not be that trustworthy based on how they have presented things to you.  Some people may play to win at any price and this manager may be that type of person and thus his interest could be to keep the good worker he found in his group.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to learn a few things. Since the interview was months ago, their needs have probably changed and that might be why you are somewhere other than you thought you would be. That is not a problem, nobody lied. It is just reality. Companies do what is in the compny's best interest not yours.

Next I am appalled that you told your boss you wouldn't take on the responsibilites you don't like. This would get you fired anywhere that I have worked espcially as a new person. Virtually all jobs have other duties as assigned, you don't get to pick what you want to work on and to expect that is naive at best and career suicide at worst.

The company has needs that change over time and you need to be willing and able to change with those needs. Sure you can move on if you get stuck somewhere you don't like, but I would not consider doing so in less than a year unless the company is going under or they aren't paying you or the atmosphere is extremely toxic unless you are very experienced. Someone with a track record can leave earlier if they find themsleves in a new position that turned out less than enjopyable, but at an entry level position a person needs to prove he or she can work with others well and do what the company asks you to do.

Further you appear to have made no effort at all to work with the people you are assigned to work with but just acted like a prima donna who was too good for them. If I were your manager, you would be the first person on the choppping block if he needs to get rid of someone because you are not a team player. You really need to look at your own attitude. The reason he doesn't transfer you may have to do with whether he would be allowed to hire a replacement. Often employees moving about create problems for a manager if there is currently a hiring freeze or if it will take a long time to get someone on board.

Comment: Completely disagree.  He interviewed for a set of responsibilities and with a set of expectations.  Now that the hiring has occurred, the deal he signed up for is being violated.  INHO, he's done everything right.  Also, he didn't reject responsibilities he didn't like, he rejected ones that were added from what he agreed to during the interview, which is perfectly reasonable.  He seems to be making great attempts at being diplomatic when he was essentially lied to.

Comment: @huntmaster, that just isn't how the world works and if you thinkit is, you are destined to be unhappy.

Comment: again, I completely disagree.  I believe you'll be happier if you treat your employment as a mutual agreement versus slavery.  In my experience, that is exactly how the world works, people do to you exactly what you let them.  And, I'm very well employed and pretty happy with my career.  You paint the picture as if the OP is walking in and putting his feet up on the desk, making demands.  They are not.  They are pushing back on what was agreed upon, with respect and diplomacy.